# Javascript Array Passed to PHP Through Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

I am trying to pass values from a multiple select listbox through Ajax to PHP.  I saw some examples in Jquery and JSON, however I am trying to accomplish this just in plain old javascript (Ajax).  Here is what I have so far (simplified):

Ajax:

```
function chooseMultiEmps(str)
  {
    var mEmpList2 = document.getElementById('mEmpList'); //values from the multi listbox
    for (var i = 0; i < mEmpList2.options.length; i++) //loop through the values
    var mEmpList = mEmpList2.options[i].value;  //create a variable to pass in string
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
   {
      //specific selection text
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 
   }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "myPage.php", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  var queryString = "&mEmpList=" + mEmpList; //query string should have multiple values
  xmlhttp.send(queryString);
}
```

I can run an `alert(mEmpList)` and get each value in individual message boxes, however when I retrieve and echo the `$_POST['mEmpList']`, I get only the first value.  Also, when I `alert(queryString)`, I get only one value.

I think I need to create a comma delimited array, and then pass that through the query string.  From there, I can use the PHP implode/explode feature to separate the values.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mEmpList2.options.length; i++) //loop through the values
var mEmpList = mEmpList2.options[i].value;  //create a variable to pass in string
```

you are redefining your mEmpList over and over again, that means only the last value is send

You could do:

```
var mEmpList = '';
for (var i = 0; i < mEmpList2.options.length; i++) { //loop through the values
    mEmpList = mEmpList +','+ mEmpList2.options[i].value;  //create a variable to pass in string
}
```

Also your `queryString` is not ok, no need for `&`

```
var queryString = "mEmpList=" + mEmpList;
```

That way at the end you will have all values delimite by comma `,`

In `PHP` you can use explode to loop each value:

```
<?php
    $string = explode(',' $_GET['mEmpList']);
    for($i=1; $i<count($string); $i++){
        echo $string[$i]."<br />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: For anyone else, to get just the selected values in the multi-listbox, you need to add: if (mEmpList2.options[i].selected) {... concatenate comma... } between the javascript for loop